# Responsive mouse move slider

Tags: javascript, carousel, mouse, move

I've got a problem. I need to build a carousel that slides, when the mouse moves left or right. 
So far so good no problem with code of people who know what they're doing (btw I'm not a web developer!). 
I used this code: codepen.io/anon/pen/mXYVMG#anon-login

But the problem is that when the window size gets smaller the sliding range is getting smaller too. But I want the carousel to slide until the last image shows up even on small or medium window/screen sizes.

Any ideas how I can handle that?

```js
jQuery(".wrapper ul").on( 'mousemove', function( event ) {{
    
    
      var mouse = {
       x: 0, // Current x-axis position of mouse
      };
    
      var containerItems = jQuery('.wrapper ul').width();
      var docWidth = jQuery(".wrapper ul").width();
    
      var docMinWidth = jQuery(".wrapper ul").width();
    
      mouse.x = event.clientX || event.pageX;
    
      mouse = mouse.x - 0;
      var Translate = mouse * 200 / docWidth;
      //console.log(Translate);
    
      jQuery('.wrapper ul').css({
                 '-webkit-transform':'translateX(-'+Translate+'%) translateY(-50%)'
                ,'-moz-transform':'translateX(-'+Translate+'%) translateY(-50%)'
                ,'transform':'translateX(-'+Translate+'%) translateY(-50%)'
            });
    
     }
     });
```

```css
 * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      outline:none;
      list-style:none;
      text-decoration:none;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      color:#000;
      background: transparent;
      border:none;
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;  
    }
    
    body {
      background: #202020;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      height: 500px;
      background: #141414;
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
      
       
    }
    
    ul {
        width: calc(400px * 10);
        float:left;
        height: 50%;
        position: relative;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        }
        
        li {
          height: 300px;
          margin:0 50px;
          background: #ccc;
          float:left;
          cursor:pointer;
          &:first-of-type {
            margin-left:800px;
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x300"/></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: the code I'm using is exactly the sam as in the codepen link above.

Comment: Yes, but I need to open a external link and come back here to answer you. I will not.

Comment: I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Pretty much. I made a snippet of it.

Comment: Did you try to change the offset of 200 according to the device width in `var Translate = mouse * 200 / docWidth;` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But that's not a responsive solution. That causes, that the carousel is sliding way longer, but also on large screens. 

Wait! Is there a way to say, that this value is 200 on large screens and maybee 500 on small screens?

some thing like "js media queries"?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. Like `var Translate = mouse * window.innerWidth / docWidth`  for example. This example is not what you have to do, but this is the way.

Comment: Ok, with "window.innerWidth" the slider doesn't stop sliding anymore.
Do you have another idea? 
Sadly I'm really bad at javascript coding.